# .Net 6.0 Backgroundservice invoke using Hangfire

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire, background-service

The app is an .Net 6.0 API and it has a background service that has to send messages in bulk. It will be along running process. I have a flag in the service logic which when turned on can only send the messages. How can I invoke this background service using and API endpoint in my application? And then I call invoke this periodically using Hangfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar use case, what I did is make that background service injectable, so I can then use it with my API call.

So in the API constructor, inject the background service and trigger the on write method to perform that specific operation. Example below -

Register the background service in your Program.cs

```
      services.AddSingleton<SchedulerBackgroundService>();
      services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SchedulerBackgroundService>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<SchedulerBackgroundService>());
```

Then in your API endpoint, inject in the constructor and trigger on each API call

```
private readonly SchedulerBackgroundService _schedulerBackgroundService;
    
public SchedulerController(SchedulerBackgroundService schedulerBackgroundService)
{
   _schedulerBackgroundService = schedulerBackgroundService;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeScheduleraction()
{
      await _schedulerBackgroundService.WriteValueAsync(…);
      return Ok();
}
```

You can inject this in Hangfire too
full bg service as below

```
public class SchedulerBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
        private Channel<SchedulerModel> _channel;

public SchedulerBackgroundService()
{
            _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<SchedulerModel>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
{
                SingleReader = true,
                SingleWriter = true,
});
        }

public async Task WriteValueAsync(SchedulerModel data)
{
  await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(data);
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            do
            {
                while (_channel.Reader.TryRead(out var data))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (data.Type)
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                    catch //(Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            } while (await _channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(stoppingToken));
        }
}
```

Comment: One problem... I want to call the ExecuteAsync and not any other function of the SchedulerBackgroundService as this will be a long running process in the background.
When I try to invoke ExceuteAsync in the controller it gives me error  Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'BackgroundService.ExecuteTask' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: you cant invoke executeasync sinces its a protected method, what you can do is have a way to keep the backgroundservice running by using Channel.

Comment: you can replace the SchedulerModel with anything, stirng, enum, int then do if else or switch case to check what you want to execute

Comment: Thanks Ismi for your response and suggestion. I have to go through the Channel thing as I have never used it. If you can suggest me any reading material for Channel, background service and Hangfire... that will be great.

Comment: you can refer to the dotnet youtube channel talking about this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT06qvQLtJ0